# sqlite3 select columns that both reference another column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have data in my_table that looks like

```
fruit1     fruit2      state
apple      orange      iowa
apple      orange      delaware
apple      orange      florida
grape      plum        texas
kiwi       orange      hawaii
kiwi       orange      alabama
```

I want to select how many times fruit 1 and 2 have been paired. the expected result would be

```
fruit1     fruit2      times_paired
apple      orange      3
grape      plum        1
kiwi       orange      2
```

I am not sure how to find pairs in sql. I know it would be something like

```
select fruit1, fruit2, count(*) from my_table order by count(*)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to `group by` the pairs.

```
select fruit1,fruit2,count(*) 
from my_table 
group by fruit1,fruit2
```

In case a pair like `a,b` needs to be treated the same as `b,a` for counting, use `least` and `greatest`.

```
select least(fruit1,fruit2),greatest(fruit1,fruit2),count(*) 
from my_table 
group by least(fruit1,fruit2),greatest(fruit1,fruit2)
```